Maintaining/Updating consumption based Logic Apps across multiple environments?
I am fairly new to Logic Apps and I am looking for a solution to promote my apps across Azure environments.
I have two Azure resource groups, one in dev and the other in production. My logic apps are not overly complex. They typically need to read data from a SharePoint list, perform some logic and then write back to the SharePoint list.
I have read online that I can manage my logic apps with VS Code and this seems to be working, however the trouble starts when I need to edit my connections. Both of my apps will have their own SharePoint list they need to connect to (dev/prod).
So my question is, could I store my Logic App code in a code repo (Azure DevOps) then use pipelines to update the connections.json file for each of my environments (in this case dev/prod). Does anyone have an example of how this would work, or is there by chance a better method to update logic apps across environments?
It can be really tedious/error-prone to update the dev app and then manually make the same changes to the production app. I know in Power Automate you can make solutions with environment variables, however I need to use Logic apps to get around the cost of making http calls.
Tools:

VS Code
Azure DevOps
Azure Logic Apps

I am looking for a way to use CI/CD for Logic Apps across environments.


So my question is, could I store my Logic App code in a code repo (Azure DevOps) then use pipelines to update the connections.json file for each of my environments (in this case dev/prod). Does anyone have an example of how this would work, or is there by chance a better method to update logic apps across environments?

Yes, it can be achieved in DevOps pipeline for Azure Logic Apps across environments.
In connections.json, you can set a placeholder #{SharePointSiteUrl}# as the actual SharePoint site URL:
{
  "connections": {
    "shared_sharepointonline": {
      "connectionId": "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/shared-sharepointonline",
      "connectionName": "shared-sharepointonline",
      "id": "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/westus/managedApis/sharepointonline",
      "api": {
        "name": "sharepointonline",
        "displayName": "SharePoint Online",
        "iconUri": "https://az818438.vo.msecnd.net/icons/sharepointonline.png",
        "brandColor": "0078d7"
      },
      "displayName": "SharePoint",
      "parameterValues": {
        "token:TenantId": "your-tenant-id",
        "token:SiteUrl": "#{SharePointSiteUrl}#",
        "token:OnPremises": false
      }
    }
  }
}

In your Azure DevOps pipeline, you can maintain a set of variables for each environment. For example, you can have a variable named SharePointSiteUrl with different values for your dev and prod environments,use extension task replace tokens to replace the placeholder with actual sharepoint site url.
- task: replacetokens@5
  displayName: 'Replace tokens'
  inputs:
    rootDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    targetFiles: '**/connections.json'
    encoding: 'auto'
    writeBOM: true
    actionOnMissing: 'warn'
    keepToken: false
    tokenPrefix: '#{'
    tokenSuffix: '}#'

This way, you can maintain a single connections.json file for all environments and use your CI/CD pipeline to update the connection details based on the target environment.
There is no exact CICD sample for sharepoint, here are some samples show some strategies that you can use to implement a continuous integration (CI) and continuous delivery (CD) pipeline for Azure Logic Apps. Hope it helps!
